# Where to put the delete command in this snipet to delete the old array

Tags: c++

Here is a code. The objective is to read data from a file word by word and store it in a char array which dynamically grows. My program is running just fine but there is one thing that I have to do but I am not doing because when I do it it shows me a window that says 'BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID' and shows a debug assertions error window. Where shud I put this delete command that deletes the old array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
char* readWordByWord(char * old)
{
    int coun = 0;
    for (int i = 0; old[i] != '\0'; i++) // to find the length of word
    {
        coun++;
    }
    char *newArr = new char[coun];
    newArr = old;
    delete[]old;  // this is where i am putting delete command to delete the previous i.e old array and then return the new one 
    return newArr;
}

int size = 100;
int main()
{
    fstream fin;
    fin.open("file.txt");
    char *p = new char[size];
    while (fin >> p)
    {

        p = readWordByWord(p);
        cout << p;
    }





    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code in `readWordByWord` does not do what you intend. You delete an array, return a pointer to that deleted array, then dereference that pointer. This is **Undefined Behavior.**

Comment: I think I was deleting the old array. So what shud I do to delete the old array and retain the new one.

Comment: @user_not_dead there is only _an_ array. Think of `old` as a pointer to this array. You are copying this pointer to `newArr` and then you delete the array behind the pointer `old`. This deletes the memory behind both `old` and `newArr`.

Comment: But I clearly create a new array  char *newArr = new char[coun];

Comment: @user_not_dead true but when you do `newArr = old` you overwrite your pointer to the array you created a line earlier. This means you can't access the memory anymore - it is leaked.

Answer (score 0):

According to your objective and code, you have some foundation in other languages.
But in c++, things not work as you want.

1. Operator "new" dynamically allocates a piece of memory on the heap and return a pointer points to the start of it.

```
    char *newArr = new char[coun];
    newArr = old;
    delete[]old;
    return newArr;
```

2. The second line here is not passing chars from old to newArr. It just makes newArr points to the address which old points. In this condition, the char[] newArr points previously will be memory leak. After deleting old, newArr points to what you don’t want.
3. `memcpy(newArr, old, (size_t)coun);` will works here instead of the second line.

```
char* readWordByWord(char * old)
{
    int coun = 0;
    for (int i = 0; old[i] != '\0'; i++) // to find the length of word
    {
        coun++;
    }
    char *newArr = new char[coun+1];
    *(newArr + coun) = '\0';
//    newArr = old;
    memcpy(newArr, old, (size_t)coun);
    delete[] old;  // this is where i am putting delete command to delete the previous i.e old array and then return the new one
    return newArr;
}
```

Add '\0' to end your char[].

Comment: I understood what u said and I tried your line instead of mine. But still, there was an error saying heap corruption detected. What should I do to simply read a file into a char array that dynamically grows?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you intended:

```
char *newArr = new char[coun];
strncpy(newArr, old, coun);
delete[]old;
```

But **this new array is not a valid C-string, since it does not end in '\0'.** Therefore you cannot (legally) pass it to `cout`. If you try, you will read past the end of the array and cause Undefined Behavior again.

If you want a valid C-string, you could do this:

```
char *newArr = new char[coun+1];
strcpy(newArr, old);
delete[]old;
```

Naturally if you don't want to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`, you can use more general tools like `memcpy`, or just copy the characters with a loop.

Comment: Your method is working .. thanks for help bruh. Can U explain a little that why it is now that delete command is not causing a crash ?

Comment: @user_not_dead: The old code caused undefined behavior; after that, the `delete` may or may not have been involved in the crash. The old code might attempt to delete the same array twice, if it didn't crash before it got that far. The new code does not cause undefined behavior, and does not attempt to delete the same array twice.

Answer (score 0):

The following four lines of your code don't do what you intend to do:

```
char *newArr = new char[coun];
newArr = old;
delete[]old;
return newArr;
```

1. The first line creates a new array, that is it allocates memory for `coun` characters and stores a pointer to the beginning of this memory in `newArr`.
2. The second line copies the pointer variable `old` into pointer variable `newArr`. You now have two pointers pointing to your array (nothing wrong with that). The pointer to the array you allocated in step 1 is lost ("leaked"). This is bad since you can't delete it anymore. If you do this over and over you might exhaust memory.
3. The array is deleted through pointer `old` (memory freed). From this point on you aren't allowed to dereference `old` and `newArr` anymore.
4. You are returning a pointer which you aren't supposed to dereference to the caller who doesn't know that. Bad things might happen from this point on.

The C++ way of solving your problem would be:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::fstream fin;
   fin.open("file.txt");

   std::string word;
   while(fin >> word) {
      std::cout << word << '\n';
   }

   fin.close();
}
```

Note that

- I'm not using dynamic memory management with `new` and `delete` here. This makes the code more efficient and more likely correct (getting dynamic memory management right by calling `new` and `delete` manually can be challenging).
- I'm using `std::string` here rather than a C string. This works reliably even for words longer than 100 characters (which might lead to a buffer overflow when copying into a C string of size 100).